# What kind of join is a normal join

Tags: sql, rdbms

Everywhere I see Inner Joins, right joins, left joins etc but what kind of join is just the regular one. e.g.

```
SELECT titel
FROM films AS f
JOIN reviews AS r ON f.id = r.film_id
```

Comment: It's an `INNER JOIN` - the `INNER` keyword is optional.

Comment: as is the `Outer` in an `Left Outer Join` or `Right Outer Join` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inner join is considered a "regular" join.